# vba access mssql inserting data

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have some problem when inserting data to database. 
I am using mssql.

```vb
Private Sub EditMethodAdd_Click()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim introw
Dim strState As String
Dim strsql1 As String
Dim strsql2 As String
Dim all As String

Dim strConn As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

MsgBox ("EditM1.Value:" & EditM1.value)


strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

strsql1 = " INSERT INTO dbo.Method(MethodID, MethodClass, Category, Description, Description2, MSA, ReqType, Equipment, Location, Spec1, Spec2, Spec3, Spec4, Spec5, Spec6, PilotingYN) "
strsql2 = "   VALUES(EditM1.value, 'Piloting', EditM3.value, Null, Null, Null, Null, EditM2.value, EditM4.value, EditM5.value, EditM6.value, EditM7.value, EditM8.value, EditM9.value, EditM10.value, Null )"


all = strsql1 & strsql2

MsgBox ("ALL" & all)


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open all, conn
MsgBox ("Insert Success")

EditMethodList.Requery

conn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

MsgBox "Data has been updated"
EditMethodList.Requery

End Sub
```

When I check the value for EditM1 by using MsgBox, it shows correct.
But I got error message like this. [image]

Is there anyone who can solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the literal value "EditM1.value" into your SQL: you should instead be sending the Value of the control:

```
strsql2 = "   VALUES(" & EditM1.value & ", 'Piloting', " & _
                         EditM3.value & ", Null,..." 'etc
```

If any of the values being sent are not numeric then they should be wrapped in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the lines:

```vb
strsql1 = ...
strsql2 = ...

all = strsql1 & strsql2
```

and write this instead

```vb
all = "INSERT INTO dbo.Method(MethodID, MethodClass, Category, Description, Description2, MSA, ReqType, Equipment, Location, Spec1, Spec2, Spec3, Spec4, Spec5, Spec6, PilotingYN) "
all = all & "VALUES(" & EditM1.value & ", 'Piloting'," & EditM3.value & ", Null, Null, Null, Null," & EditM2.value & "," & EditM4.value & "," 
all = all & EditM5.value & "," & EditM6.value & "," & EditM7.value & "," & EditM8.value & "," & EditM9.value & "," & EditM10.value & ", Null )"
```

If you insert EditM1.value into doublequotes, as you did, VBA read it as a string and it does not refer to its value. You need to concatenate string and values with & to create your query.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a parameter query, here is an explanation and example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057683/3820271