# VBA Compile Error on Function Call

Tags: sql, string, vba, ms-access

so I'm trying to run this SQL script within a function I call and it's giving me a "Compile Error: Object Required" when I try to run it!

Code calling the function

```vb
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

   Call Load_Username(Username)

End Sub
```

Function being called

```vb
Private Sub Load_Username(Text As String)

    Dim SQL As String

    Set SQL = "UPDATE tbleUsername " & _
              "SET Username = '" & Text & "' " & _
              "WHERE ID = 1"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Text is a reserved word. Suggest you use a different name for the variable and see if that helps - like txtText. Technically, you are not calling a function, you are calling a sub. I prefer `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Comment: @June7 `Text` is not a keyword, what are you talking about?

Comment: Is tbleUsername present in your db? shouldn't it be tblUsername?

Comment: Text is a reserved word - it has special meaning in JET. Using reserved words for other purposes can cause unexpected results. Might not be the case here but best practice is to avoid using reserved words to name anything. http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T

Comment: Sorry guys, I had those not declared cause I just got lazy... That wasn't the issue though, it was because I was using "Set"

Comment: note that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. you should escape the quoted string.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre [Please don't do that, and don't suggest it either. It's wrong in so many terrible ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057683/1188513)

Comment: For the record, I disagree somewhat with that post. Using parameterised sql is a solution, and probably the best solution, but almost no-one (in the Access world, anyway) does it. The important thing is to *escape* user input if injecting it into SQL. That *is* sanitising it (and is what parameterisation does internally). Not to mention, if ```username``` here contains a single quote, you'll get an error (not actually likely for a username, but somewhat likely for general strings). I have a function ```q()``` that single quotes and escapes a string, I use it for all quick-and-dirty SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Dim SQL As String
Set SQL = "string literal"
```

You can't use `Set` to assign a string literal. Use `Set` to assign *object references*. That assignment is illegal, because an object is required. Hence, *Object required*.

Two possible fixes:

1. Remove the `Set` keyword and use the wonderful implicit value assignment syntax.
2. Replace the `Set` keyword with the obsolete `Let` keyword for a long-deprecated explicit value assignment syntax. Only suggesting because I'm seeing you use the long-deprecated `Call` keyword too.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help on that :)

Another question for you, it's prompting me with a "Are you sure you'd like to replace this field?"

Is there any way to remove this prompt so it will run without a confirmation message?

Comment: I know my VBA pretty much inside out, but I don't work in Access. Excel.Application has a `DisplayAlerts` property that you can set to `False` to achieve something similar. Maybe Access has something similar?

Comment: Darn, completely overlooked the Set on string variable. `CurrentDb.Execute(SQL)`  will not trigger message. Otherwise, use `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` and then turn back on with `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`.

Comment: @June7 That worked flawlessly! You guys are awesome, thank you for everything :)

Comment: I appreciate the lesson about the `Let` keyword. Haven't seen it outside of classes anywhere (as a young programmer), and always fun to learn new things!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should define variable `Username` before `call function LoadUsername(UserName)`

Comment: Nope. That would not give the complile error OP is having.